# Sencha Touch: avoiding blank line while combining Carousel and Toolbar

Tags: sencha-touch-2, mobile-website

I'm having an issue while scrolling between items in the vertical carousel:
[image: screenshot]

The blank division has the same height as the toolbar. Is there any way to avoid the blank line? This is my current code:

```
Ext.define('eltirabuzon.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video',
        'Ext.carousel.Carousel'
    ],
    config: {
        cls: 'cards',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        defaults: {
            flex: 1
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.Carousel',{
    fullscreen: true,
    height: '100%',
    direction: 'vertical',
    directionLock: true,
    indicator: false,
    defaults: {
        directionLock: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0
    },
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            ui: 'dark',
            title: 'El Tirabuzon',
            items: [{
              xtype: 'button',
                text: '',
                docked: 'left',
                ui: 'action',
                cls: 'button-options'
            }]
        },
        {
            html: 'rtutorial',
            style: {
                'color': '#FFF',
                'background-color': '#BBB',
                'background-image': 'url(http://gastonbercun.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/steve-jobsNews.jpg)',
                'background-size': 'cover'
            }
        },
        {
            html: 'noticia',
            style: {
                'color': '#FFF',
                'background-color': '#BBB',
                'background-image': 'url(http://blog.ciencianueva.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/steve-jobs-renuncia-a-apple.jpeg)',
                'background-size': 'cover'
            }
        },
        {
            html: 'lista',
            style: {
                'color': '#FFF',
                'background-color': '#BBB',
                'background-image': 'url(http://www.biography.com/imported/images/Biography/Images/Galleries/Steve%20Jobs/steve-jobs-photo-NeXT-intro-07-sized.jpg)',
                'background-size': 'cover'
            }
        },
        {
            html: 'resena',
            style: {
                'color': '#FFF',
                'background-color': '#CCC',
                'background-image': 'url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-HRJITwGr_Vk/TlYaxYFxoKI/AAAAAAAAAPI/3ofib-Z1VgI/s1600/ipadjobsjpg-1426c786c4434809.jpg)',
                'background-size': 'cover'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: You need to use 'docked' instead of 'dock' since sencha touch 2.0.0

Comment: @TDeBailleul I added that change to the code, but the blank line is still being displayed. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you inspect the DOM using broser tool and see what exactly is that white element? If not html element, it could be stray `margin` or `padding` or some other CSS tweak